# error: conflicting types for ‘whatever’

Tags: c, gcc, embedded, mips

I'm working on an embedded systems which provides an interface with certain types.

The problem is by including certain headers from c standard library I get an `error: conflicting types`

I use `gettimeofday` and I'm only using `struct timeval`, yet for using this `sys/time.h` also drags in `time_t` which interferes with the one defined by the system.

I can't touch either of those pieces of code and I need them both.

Is there a way to get around such issues? (I should be able to use the systems' declared types and some functions declared in c headers, headers which contain some declarations already done by the system.)

Comment: If you need different things with the same name in the same source file, you don't have much choices other than rename one of the things.

Comment: @netrom I make use gettimeofday and I'm only using struct timeval, yet for using this I sys/time.h also drags time_t which interferes with the one defined by the system.

Comment: Which system are you using?  If it's redefining standard types, then that's a problem.

Comment: Are you sure the standard C and posix headers are available for use on that embedded device ? And that there isn't a similar API in the specific system headers ?

Comment: Long term, you will be wanting to fix the C library port so that its idea of `time_t` matches the operating system's.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use macros to rename one of the `time_t` typedefs without modifying any headers:

```
#define time_t LIBC_time_t
#include <sys/time.h>
#undef time_t

#include <header_which_defines_the_time_t_you_want.h>
```

This is not guaranteed to work, but it does work a lot of the time.

Comment: Nice and simple. It might be a bit delicate, if someone moves #includes around, or there are two time_t fields. Otherwise, nifty.

Answer (score 2):

One way to get around this, as a more or less last resort is to introduce another level of abstracion, and provide wrapper APIs to isolate the troublesome headers.

If you have something like this:

my_file.c:

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <some_system_header.h>

void foo(void)
{
     struct timeval tv;
     gettimeofday(&tv);
     ....
}
```

turns into

my_gettimeofday.c:

```
#include <sys/time.h> //only sys.time.h here, no system headers
#include "my_gettimeofday.h"

void my_gettimeofday(struct my_timeval *my_tv)
{
   struct timeval tv;
   gettimeofday(&tv);
   my_tv->sec  = tv.tv_sec;
   my_tv->usec = tv.tv_usec;
}
```

my_gettimeofday.h:

```
struct my_timeval {
   long sec, usec; //adjust to your platform if needed
};
void my_gettimeofday(struct my_timeval *my_tv);
```

my_file.c:

```
//no sys/time.h here.
#include <some_system_header.h>
#include "my_gettimeofday.h"
void foo(void)
{
     struct my_timeval tv;
     my_gettimeofday(&tv);
     ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is only one function (gettimeofday), and one type, build a 'wrapper' function in a seperate source code file, include the correct header for the call of gettimeofday.

```
int my_gettimeofday(struct my_timeval *restrict tp, void *restrict tzp) {
    timeval t;
    t.time_t = my_timeval.time_t;
    // ...
    int ret = gettimeofday(&t, tzp);
    my_timeval.time_t = t.time_t;
    // .. copy the others
}
```

Invent the new type, struct my_timeval, which is the same contents as the one that is being conflicted with. The conflicts have been seperated.

Is that it?